# Qual é o equivalente em RegExp do split("") em JS?

Tags: javascript, regex

Eu quero splitar o número PI 3.141593 num array que não contenha o '.' e todos números separados. Tentei fazer .split(/[\.""]/g) mas não deu certo. Quais seriam as soluções equivalentes evitando a força bruta?

Comment: Em uma linha sem regex (que provavelmente não é a ferramenta certa para esse tipo de operação): `[...Math.PI.toString().replace('.', '')];`.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Testa aí, aqui deu certo:

```js
const pi = 3.141593;

const piArray = pi.toString().replace(".", "").split("");

console.log(piArray);
```

Se precisar montar uma string e não um array, aplica toString() na variável piArray depois.

```js
const pi = 3.141593;

const piArray = pi.toString().replace(".", "").split("");

console.log(piArray.toString());
```